# How to read namespace declarations using XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have to trasform the raw response of **any** OData feed (ATOM) in the form of a tree with expandable/collapsable nodes. For this purpose I am converting the raw response into HTML using XSLT transformation.

The problem is that response from some services have the feed element with namespace declarations as attributes. (eg: feed xmlns:d= ..., xmlns:m= ...).In my final output these namespace declarations are not displayed.

The XSLT processor ignores them while processing the attributes.(I am using the XPath expression "@*".) Is there a way to extract them using XSLT and display the namespace declaration content as-is in the trasformed output ?

Note that I get to know about these namespace declaration attributes at runtime in the OData response. I have no information before the query executes.

UPDATE:

**Input** : (RAW XML Entry)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><entry xml:base="http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><id>http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Regions(1)</id><category term="NorthwindModel.Region" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" title="Region" href="Regions(1)" /><link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Territories" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Territories" href="Regions(1)/Territories" /><title /><updated>2014-03-17T10:24:14Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:RegionID m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:RegionID><d:RegionDescription xml:space="preserve">Eastern                                           </d:RegionDescription></m:properties></content></entry>
```

**Desired Output**: (The same ATOM entry,as a XML tree, pretty printed with expandable/collapsable nodes)

```
-<entry xml:base="http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">

-<id>
   http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Regions(1)
</id>
<category term="NorthwindModel.Region" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
<link rel="edit" title="Region" href= "Regions(1)" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Territories" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Territories" href= "Regions(1)/Territories" />
<title/>
<updated>2014-03-17T10:06:25Z</updated>

-<author>
   <name/>
</author>

-<content type="application/xml">

-<m:properties>
   <d:RegionID m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:RegionID>
   <d:RegionDescription xml:space="preserve">Eastern </d:RegionDescription>
</m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
```

**Output which I am getting.**

```
    -<entry xml:base="http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/">

    -<id>
        http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Regions(1)
    </id>
    <category term="NorthwindModel.Region"    scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
    <link rel="edit" title="Region" href= "Regions(1)" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Territories" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Territories" href= "Regions(1)/Territories" />
    <title/>
    <updated>2014-03-17T10:06:25Z</updated>

    -<author>
        <name/>
    </author>

    -<content type="application/xml">

    -<m:properties>
       <d:RegionID m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:RegionID>
       <d:RegionDescription xml:space="preserve">Eastern </d:RegionDescription>
    </m:properties>
    </content>
    </entry>
```

Please note the missing name space declarations in the output's "entry" root element.

The output is a HTML which displays pretty-printed xml, with expandable/collapsable nodes and since it should display the data as-is, namespace declarations are required to be displayed in the output HTML.
Clicking on the "-" symbols collapses the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If a declaration is already in scope (remember, namespace bindings are inherited to children), it will not need to be redeclared and most XML serializers will not generate it. You haven't shown us an example yet, but I'd bet your output is fine as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Namespace declarations in your source XML appear in the XPath data model as namespace nodes (not attribute nodes).

You need to make clear what you want to do with the namespaces. You're saying that you are generating HTML, but you also say you want to copy the namespaces to the output. That seems inconsistent. Show us you input and desired output.

Comment: Hi Michael. Updated the Post with my input and desired output format.

Comment: Hi Michael. Updated the Post with my input and desired output format.An image of output would have been more informative but I dont have prmissions to upload an image yet. The output should be something similar when the following link is viewed in a browser http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/. (Pretty printed with expandable/collapsable nodes.)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't managed to spot the difference between your actual output and your desired output (never was very good at "spot the ball" competitions), but from your revised description of the problem it sounds as if you should be using the namespace axis to find the in-scope namespaces for an element (in the same way as you are currently using the attribute axis).

The only tricky part is that the namespace axis will give you all the namespaces for an element and you probably only want to show those that are different from the namespaces of the parent element.

The details depend on whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 - you need to tell us!